# Create an aggregated dataframe from column of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of issues pulled from a Github repo using Pygithub. It is currently structured like the below -

```
assignees  |  open?  |  issue_id
n/a           yes        1
[p1, p2]      no         2
[p5]          no         3
[p1, p5, p2]  yes        4
```

I would like to modify/pivot table it so that it looks like -

```
assignee  |   yes   |    no
n/a            1          0
p1             1          1
p2             1          1
p5             1          1
```

I tried `pd.Series(Counter(chain.from_iterable(df['assignees'])))` but this split up the n/a values to three separate values ("n", "/", and "a"). I'm also not sure how that would work in regards to the values in another column. I was looking into a reverse group_by method but so far, my googling skills have failed me.

To create the test dataframe:

```
data = {'assignees': ['n/a', ['p1', 'p2'], ['p5'], ['p1', 'p5', 'p2']], 
        'open?': ['yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes'], 
        'issue_id': [1,2,3,4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I do not get it. What exactly do you want us to help you with? Can you be more specific than just show the final result? What constitutes as 'open' and 'closed'?

Comment: @EAB certainly. Basically, I want to create a pivot table based on the list values to count the number of issues that user has that are either open or closed. I am struggling to figure out a way to do this.
I will update the desired result as I realize my column names aren't exactly intuitive ('open' constituted as a 'yes' result in the df[ 'open?'] column)

Comment: I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, let's try pandas 0.25.0+ `explode`:

```
df_out = df.set_index(['open?','issue_id'])['assignees'].explode().reset_index()

df_out.pivot_table(index='assignees', 
                   columns='open?', 
                   values='issue_id', 
                   aggfunc='count', 
                   fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
open?      no  yes
assignees         
n/a         0    1
p1          1    1
p2          1    1
p5          1    1
```